# attempt to construct a uncountable measure zero set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to construct a uncountable measure zero set

**this is my 1st attempt:**

let $A=${$x\in \Bbb R | x $'s decimal places has infinitely many zero's }

for example $1=1.000...\in A$, $1.010101....\in A$ and $\pi \in A$

it seems like to me this set is uncountable, what about measure of $A$

is $m(A)=0$ or $m(A)>0$ ?

**edit-**

I am trying to construct the set **without using cantor set**

Comment: I am not an expert in measures, but if I am informed right, the normal numbers form a set with measure $1$. If so, then your attempt fails because every normal number has infinite many zeros in the decimal expansion.

Comment: Claim: no matter how it will described, the answer will be (a subset of) a countable union of Cantor-like sets. I'd like to be proved wrong :D (your proposed set is the complement of such a set, therefore it has full measure; in fact by replacing "infinitely" with "finitely" you obtain a correct answer).

Answer (score 2):

A cantor set is a zero-set and uncountable and can be built as follows:consider interval $[0,1]\in R$. Equipartition it by 3 subsets ,namely, $[0,1/3],[1/3,2/3],[2/3,1]$ and remove the middle sub-interval [1/3,2/3].
Perform the same procedure on remaining intervals $[0,1/3],[2/3,1]$ and construct intervals $[0,1/9],[2/9,1/3],[2/3,7/9],[8/9,1]$. Following this idea till infinity you will finally have an uncountable zero-set.

Comment: thanks, I know about the cantor set, I tried to come with another approach

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

A classic example is *Cantor's ternary set*:
$$K_3=\biggl\{\sum_{i\ge 1}\frac{x_i}{3^i}\;\Bigm|\forall i\ge 1, x_i\in\{0,2\}\biggr\}$$
i.e. the set of real numbers in $[0,1]$ which a base $3$ expansion without $1$ among the ternary digits.

Comment: thanks, I know about the cantor set, I tried to come with another approach

Answer (score 1):

Since your question seems to be about your choice of $A$ in particular, I'll address that instead of supplying a different option (which others have done very well).

The complement of your $A$ consists of all $x$ with only finitely many zeroes. All such $x$ are rational (because, for example, $0.10010111111\ldots$ is the same as $0.10011$). The set of *all* rationals has measure $0$, so the complement of $A$ has measure zero. So $A$ has (very) positive measure. Others have suggested the Cantor set instead, which would be an excellent option.

Comment: $0.12112111211112\ldots$ isn't rational, but still only has finitely many zeroes.

Comment: @Arthur I suspect Reese read "binary" in place of "decimal" (I certainly did at first pass).